# Cardinality of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For if I understand this correctly, given any two sets X and Y, $card(X^Y)=cardX^{cardY}.$ However, from what I read, $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is supposedly countable. It is also said that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0.$ How is this consistent? Are one of these two statements incorrect?

Comment: The power set of $\mathbb N$ is not countable

Comment: *Where* did you read that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is countable?

Comment: What is countable, however, is the subset of those cases with finitely many $1$s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the statement "$\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is countable" is incorrect. It is uncountable (by the standard diagonal argument).

Comment: Thank you! I was completely confused when I read the statements claiming that this set was countable.

Comment: @JDivision Where did you read it's countable?

Comment: http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~szlam/2012-fall-308/homework10_solutions.pdf @José Carlos Santos

Comment: @JDivision Where in that pdf does it say that $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is countable?

Comment: Mia culpa. I misread the notation. I read ${0, 1}^\mathbb{N}$ as “the set of functions from {0,1} to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @JDivision I thought so, that's why I asked :).

Comment: Why do we have this notation? It seems more natural to have your target in the exponent and source in the base.

Comment: @JDivision That's actually one of the rare instances where a question about notation does have a satisfactory answer: Let $m,n > 0$ be natural numbers. Then there are exactly $m^n$ functions $f \colon n \to m$. Hence, if we let $m^n$ also be the collection of all of these functions, we have $\mathrm{card}(m^n) = m^n$. This motivated the notation and since there is rarely any confusion about it (in the appropriate context), this notation has stood the test of time (thus far).

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is uncountable, and in fact, you can construct a fairly intuitive surjective function from $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ to $[0,1]$ by mapping

$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots)\mapsto 0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\dots_2$$

where the right side is a binary expansion, i.e.

$$0.a_1a_2a_3\dots = \frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{4}+\frac{a_3}{8} + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} a_n$$

It's easy to see that all numbers in $[0,1]$ (an uncountable set) are covered. Since only a countable number of numbers are covered more than once (and they are always covered no more than twice), it's easy to modify the function to a (not as nice looking) bijection, but that's not even neccesary if all you want to do is prove your original set is not countable.

Comment: When you say that [0,1] is countable, you mean uncountable, right?

Comment: @JDivision Yeah, sorry, that was a typo